# Probability of age of person renewing insurance?

Tags: probability

Suppose that 5% of policy holders in a certain car insurance company do not renew their policies the following year. From the previous data 90% of people who renew policy are greater than or equal to 40 years old and 60% of people who do not renew the policy are less than 40 years old.

a) When you pick one policy holder, what is the probability that the policy holder's age is younger than 40?

b) Given that the one you pick is younger than 40, what is the probability that they are not going to renew the policy next year?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Where do you get stuck?

Comment: A bald statement of an exercise-quality problem leaves your Readers guessing where you might have run into difficulty.  Is it with the formulation of a probability space appropriate to the question(s)?  Is it with knowing how to express the given information symbolically?  Is it with algebraic steps?

Comment: I am stuck on where to get started. I'm not sure how to organize this information and then where to start computing the probabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with writing down the information you are given:

$P(Does Not Renew) \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad= 0.05$
$P(Renew) = 1- P(DoesNotRenew) \quad\quad\quad\;= 0.95$
$P(>= 40\; |\; Renew) \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\;= 0.9$
$P(< 40\; |\; Renew) = 1 - P(>=40\;|\;Renew) \quad= 0.1$
$P(< 40\; |\; Does Not Renew) \quad\quad\quad\;\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad= 0.6$

a) By Law Of Total Probability:
   $\quad P(<40) = P(<40 \; | \; Renew)P(Renew) + P(<40 \; | \; DoesNotRenew)P(DoesNotRenew)$
   $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad = (0.1)(0.95) + (0.6)(0.05) = 0.125$

b) By Bayes Theorem:
$\quad P(DoesNotRenew\; | < 40)P(<40) = P(<40\;|\;Does Not Renew)P(Does Not Renew)$
$\quad P(DoesNotRenew\; | < 40)(0.125) = (0.6)(0.05)$
$\quad P(DoesNotRenew\; | < 40) = (0.6)(0.05)/0.125$